# Edge weights and node labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I am trying to draw a graph with node and edge weights. Here is what I've managed to do so far. I've placed node names. but I want to place node weights under the circles. And I want to put edge weights too. I am not getting anywhere how to put edge label. Here is my current code.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
\node[vertex][](t) at (2, 0) {$ \omega_{i} $};
\node[vertex][](r1) at (1, 2) {$ r^{\omega_{i}}_{1} $};
\node[vertex][](r2) at (3, 2) {$ r^{\omega_{i}}_{2} $};
\node[vertex][](q1) at (0,-2) {$ q^{\omega_{i}}_{1} $};
\node[vertex][](q2) at (2,-2) {$ q^{\omega_{i}}_{2} $};
\node[vertex][](q3) at (4,-2) {$ q^{\omega_{i}}_{2} $};
\begin{scope}[every path/.style={-, dashed}]
       \draw (t) -- (q1);
       \draw (t) -- (q2); 
       \draw (t) -- (q3);

       \draw (t) -- (r1);
       \draw (t) -- (r2);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[every path/.style={-}]
       \draw (r1) -- (q1);
       \draw (r1) -- (q2);
       \draw (r1) -- (q3);
       \draw (r2) -- (q1);
       \draw (r2) -- (q2);
       \draw (r2) -- (q3);
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You can add an edge label like this: `\draw (t) -- node [anchor=south] {$p_1$} (q1);` You will have to play around a bit with getting the anchors right (choose `north`, `south west`, etc to see the effect). Other parameters you may want to look at is `inner sep` (which is the white space around the label) and `pos` (which determines where on the edge the label will appear).

Comment: I don't want to specify anchor direction. also I want to align the label text by the edge line

Comment: So you want the labels to be positioned automatically? I don't think that's possible. Adding node weights, by the way, can be done by `\node[vertex, label=below:$10$](t) at (2, 0) {$ \omega_{i} $};`  (also note that you don't need the extra `[]`).

Comment: That is easy with nodes. but aligning labels with edges is tuf. I think there is some rotation required.

Comment: Ah, if you want the labels to be rotated automatically, this can actually be done automatically. See my answer below. You'll still need some positioning, but it gets a bit easier.

Comment: I'd suggest to read pgfmanual section 3 "Tutorial: A Petri-Net for Hagen". There you can find "Adding Labels next to nodes" and "Adding Labels next to lines" which is what you want to know.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an edge label like this: `\draw (t) -- node [anchor=south] {$p_1$} (q1)`. You will have to play around a bit with getting the anchors right (choose `north`, `south west`, etc., to see the effect). Other parameters you may want to look at is `inner sep` (which is the white space around the label) and `pos` (which determines where on the edge the label will appear).

Adding node weights can be done by `\node[vertex, label=below:$10$](t) at (2, 0) {$ \omega_{i} $};` (also note that you don't need the extra `[]`).

Here you go:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle, draw]
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
\node[vertex, label=right:$1$](t) at (4, 0) {$ \omega_{i} $};
\node[vertex, label=above:$2$](r1) at (2, 2) {$ r^{\omega_{i}}_{1} $};
\node[vertex, label=above:$3$](r2) at (6, 2) {$ r^{\omega_{i}}_{2} $};
\node[vertex, label=below:$4$](q1) at (0,-2) {$ q^{\omega_{i}}_{1} $};
\node[vertex, label=below:$5$](q2) at (4,-2) {$ q^{\omega_{i}}_{2} $};
\node[vertex, label=below:$6$](q3) at (8,-2) {$ q^{\omega_{i}}_{2} $};
\begin{scope}[every path/.style={-, dashed}, every node/.style={inner sep=1pt}]
       \draw (t) -- node [anchor=north west] {$1$} (q1);
       \draw (t) -- node [anchor=west]  {$2$} (q2); 
       \draw (t) -- node [anchor=north east] {$3$} (q3);

       \draw (t) -- node [anchor=north east] {$4$} (r1);
       \draw (t) -- node [anchor=north west] {$5$} (r2);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[every path/.style={-}, every node/.style={inner sep=1pt}]
       \draw (r1) -- node [anchor=east] {$6$} (q1);
       \draw (r1) -- node [pos=0.15, anchor=north east] {$7$} (q2);
       \draw (r1) -- node [pos=0.15, anchor=south west] {$8$} (q3);
       \draw (r2) -- node [pos=0.15, anchor=south east] {$9$} (q1);
       \draw (r2) -- node [pos=0.15, anchor=north west] {$10$} (q2);
       \draw (r2) -- node [anchor=west] {$11$} (q3);
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want your edge labels to be rotated automatically, you can use `sloped`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle, draw]
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
\node[vertex, label=right:$1$](t) at (4, 0) {$ \omega_{i} $};
\node[vertex, label=above:$2$](r1) at (2, 2) {$ r^{\omega_{i}}_{1} $};
\node[vertex, label=above:$3$](r2) at (6, 2) {$ r^{\omega_{i}}_{2} $};
\node[vertex, label=below:$4$](q1) at (0,-2) {$ q^{\omega_{i}}_{1} $};
\node[vertex, label=below:$5$](q2) at (4,-2) {$ q^{\omega_{i}}_{2} $};
\node[vertex, label=below:$6$](q3) at (8,-2) {$ q^{\omega_{i}}_{2} $};
\begin{scope}[every path/.style={-, dashed}, every node/.style={sloped, inner sep=1pt}]
       \draw (t) -- node [anchor=north] {$1$} (q1);
       \draw (t) -- node [anchor=south]  {$2$} (q2); 
       \draw (t) -- node [anchor=north] {$3$} (q3);

       \draw (t) -- node [anchor=north] {$4$} (r1);
       \draw (t) -- node [anchor=north] {$5$} (r2);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[every path/.style={-}, every node/.style={sloped, inner sep=1pt}]
       \draw (r1) -- node [anchor=south] {$6$} (q1);
       \draw (r1) -- node [pos=0.15, anchor=north] {$7$} (q2);
       \draw (r1) -- node [pos=0.15, anchor=south] {$8$} (q3);
       \draw (r2) -- node [pos=0.15, anchor=south] {$9$} (q1);
       \draw (r2) -- node [pos=0.15, anchor=north] {$10$} (q2);
       \draw (r2) -- node [anchor=south] {$11$} (q3);
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]